Algorithm that sorts cells on the same distance clockwise
I am coding a board mini-game while learning java and I would like to find the most efficient algorithm to my problem (I found one but it looks inefficient).
Context :
The board is a x,y matrix starting from top left, each coordinate is a cell.
We have a player on the board, placed in a cell of the matrix.
Problem :
Given a list of all the cells of the same range from the player, sort the list clockwise starting from the top cell (above the player).
I will link a picture below that should make much more sense
Examples : The player is at coordinate 3,3

Given the list of all cells of 1 range from the player, unsorted [(2,3),(3,4),(3,2),(4,3)], we need to sort the list clockwise [(3,2),(4,3),(3,4),(2,3)].
Given the list of all cells of 2 range from the player, unsorted [(2,2),(2,4),(1,3),(3,1),(3,5),(4,4),(4,2),(5,3)], we need to sort the list clockwise [(3,1),(4,2),(5,3),(4,4),(3,5),(2,4),(1,3),(2,2)].


My probably inefficient algorithm :
Create 4 lists of each direction and merge them : (o = origin/player cell)

x >= ox and y > oy, sort on ascending x
x > ox and y <= oy, sort on descending x
x <= ox and y < oy, sort on descending x
x < ox and y >= oy, sort on ascending x

Sorry for any possible confusion as my english isn't perfect.

Given a list you code the game, but do not create that list?

@greybeard I do, I just didn't want to over complexify my post but maybe I should have. What this is really about is target order : from closest to farthest and if 2 targets are on the same distance from the player, do the clockwise order. So whenever there is more than 1 target on the same distance, I create a list of X targets and order them clockwise.

Your approach doesn't look bad. It may be simplified a bit: for example, we may sort all cells $(x, y)$ with $x \ge ox$ on ascending $y$ and cells with $x < ox$ on descending $y$. And this algorithm is already linear on number of cells if we use radix sort.
However if you are given all cells on the same distance (using Manhattan metrics, as far as I see) and no additional information then the only essential information is the distance itself. I mean that knowledge of player's position and distance $d$ is enough to list all cells on distance $d$, there is no need to sort given cells at all. Indeed, subtract $d$ from player's $y$-coordinate to get the topmost cell on distance $d$. Then increment (by $1$) both coordinates $d$ times, then decrement $x$-coordinate and increment $y$-coordinate $d$ times, then decrement both coordinates $d$ times and finally increment $x$-coordinate and decrement $y$-coordinate $d - 1$ times. To simplify it further note that values $d_x$ and $d_y$ added to $x$- and $y$-coordinates are changed every time in the following way $d_x' = -d_y$ and $d_y' = d_x$.

I didn't know it was called Manhattan metrics, but yes this what I am using. Thank you very much this is much better !
